# Unable to find Twitter uid from Users Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth, twitter-oauth

I've been trying to play around with Omniauth-Twitter and am stuck with an infuriating problem. I'm unable to match my session id to the stored Twitter uid. I used Ryan Bates' screencast to assist me through the walkthrough.

Here's my session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  session[:user_id] = user.uid
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
end

def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed out!"
end
end
```

Here's my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid = auth["uid"]
    user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
  end
end
end
```

Here's my application controller that should be able to assign my Twitter persona to the current user variable:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
helper_method :current_user

private

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
end
```

On the front end, I'm trying to essentially display the user name, like so:

```
<% if current_user %>
Welcome <%= current_user.name %>!
<%= link_to "Sign Out", signout_path %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "Sign in with Twitter", "/auth/twitter" %>
```

When I run the application and hit "Sign in with Twitter", I'm getting an error that says:

"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. Couldn't find User with id= "

The server's highlighting the current_user method as the error point. Any help would be appreciated? I'll gladly provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing the user `id`, which is automatically assigned by the database, with `uid`, which is Twitter's id. Either:

1. Change `session[:user_id] = user.uid` to `session[:user_id] = user.id`. Or
2. Change

   ```
   def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
   end
   ```

   to

   ```
   def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find_by(uid: session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
   end
   ```

Personally, I would go for the first option.

Comment: Worked like a charm! StackOverflow doesn't want me to post a thank you comment, but I'll do it anyway. Thanks!